# How to count how many times a substring appears in string

Tags: python, arrays, string

Say I have a string of s1 and s2. I wanted to be able to make a program which tells how many times s1 appears in s2. This is my attempt:

```
char1 = int(input("number of character of s1: "))
s1 = str(input("insert string 1: "))
char2 = int(input("number of character of s2: "))
s2 = str(input("insert string 2: "))
n = 0
bool = True
start = 0
while bool:
    a = s2.find(s1,start)                    
    if a == -1:          
        bool = False
    else:                
        n+=1        
        start = a+1
print("s1 appears", n, "times in s2.")
```

For instance I have s1 as "the" and s2 as "the bird the apple the chair" then the output should be:

> s1 appears 3 times in s2.

The problem is, I can't use some functions such as: find, sum, count, max, min, len, try, break, etc.

I'm still a few days old learning python, which is no wonder why I'm still learning array and string--and I can't think of a way for the alternative of the find function that I code. I know I'm very close to get the desired output (since my code actually works), however the find() function is banned

Comment: As a note on question writing, replace `input` with hardcoded values when posssible. Then you can show us the exact inputs and outputs you expect. It would be common to put this in a function and use `unittest` to test multiple combinations including edge conditions like an empty `s1`.

Comment: I would just pick up any solution involving `find`, `sum`, `count`, etc. and just replace the built-in functions with a custom implementation to please your instructor.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a comprehension / generator expression to match and count -

```py
times = sum(1 if word == s1 else 0 for word in s2.split())
print(f's1 appears {times} times in s2')
```

**Output**

```
s1 appears 3 times in s2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could repeatedly compare the wanted string to slices of the target string. For instance, with "the", you could take slices `[0:3]`, `[1:4]`, etc... until you find your match. Return the index of the slice you found plus the the length of the search word and that is the basis for the next find.

(Note: Purposely avoiding `len()`)

```
def my_find(to_find, string, start=0):
    find_len = 0
    for _ in to_find:
        find_len += 1
    string_len = 0
    for _ in string:
        string_len += 1
    for i in range(start, string_len - find_len):
        if string[i:i+find_len] == to_find:
            return i + find_len
    return -1

s1 = "the"
s2 = "the bird the apple the chair"

n = 0
bool = True
start = 0
while bool:
    a = my_find(s1, s2, start)               
    if a == -1:          
        bool = False
    else:                
        n+=1        
        start = a+1
print("s1 appears", n, "times in s2.")
```

Comment: nice one but you use `len`:(

Comment: @cards  - oops, I'll work on that.

Comment: I thought to get 1st the powerset of `s2` (to not depend on `len`) and then filter it but it is very very slow... I am curious if you can find another way

Comment: @cards  - updated to count characters instead of using `len`. I don't think speed is the point of this exercise!

Comment: Ahaha nice trick! I implemented the power set recursively but when applied to `s2` my compiler crashed...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using the `split()` method of string so you can iterate through each word in `s2`. This makes it so you don't have to do any string manipulation or use any functions like `find`.

```
s1 = str(input("insert string 1: "))
s2 = str(input("insert string 2: "))

n=0
for word in s2.split():
    if s1 == word:
        n+=1

print(f'"{s1}" appears {n} times in "{s2}"')
```

Comment: This assumes that OP is looking for exact words, not phrases, partial words or even a subsequence in a string of characters that encode something else.

Comment: @tdelaney Agreed. It felt like a safe assumption since they are a few days into python coding and this smells like homework. But... OP if you aren't looking for words to match, but rather to count any substring, like "hi" is in the string "hi, bob! My name is hildegard and this my friend steve" 3 times, then this approach won't work.